# Read data from json response

Tags: json, delphi

I am developing an application with Delphi 10 Seattle.

I am trying to read a value of an item from JSON.

For example :

```json
{  
  "findCompletedItemsResponse":[  
    {  
      "ack":[  
        "Success"
      ],
      "version":[  
        "1.13.0"
      ],
      "timestamp":[  
        "2016-06-02T16:07:36.736Z"
      ],
      "searchResult":[  
        {  
          "@count":"2",
          "item":[  
            {  
              "itemId":[  
                "172168793372"
              ],
              "title":[  
                "Nikon D5000 12.3 MP Digital SLR Camera (Body Only with Accessories)"
              ],
              "globalId":[  
                "EBAY-US"
              ],
              "primaryCategory":[  
                {  
                  "categoryId":[  
                    "31388"
                  ],
                  "categoryName":[  
                    "Digital Cameras"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "galleryURL":[  
                "http:\/\/thumbs1.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mlRCNAriHPzowbSV9Q7ZFAg\/140.jpg"
              ],
              "viewItemURL":[  
                "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/Nikon-D5000-12-3-MP-Digital-SLR-Camera-Body-Only-Accessories-\/172168793372"
              ],
              "paymentMethod":[  
                "PayPal"
              ],
              "autoPay":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "postalCode":[  
                "02806"
              ],
              "location":[  
                "Barrington,RI,USA"
              ],
              "country":[  
                "US"
              ],
              "shippingInfo":[  
                {  
                  "shippingServiceCost":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"0.0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shippingType":[  
                    "Free"
                  ],
                  "shipToLocations":[  
                    "US"
                  ],
                  "expeditedShipping":[  
                    "true"
                  ],
                  "oneDayShippingAvailable":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "handlingTime":[  
                    "2"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "sellingStatus":[  
                {  
                  "currentPrice":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"178.5"
                    }
                  ],
                  "convertedCurrentPrice":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"178.5"
                    }
                  ],
                  "bidCount":[  
                    "13"
                  ],
                  "sellingState":[  
                    "EndedWithSales"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "listingInfo":[  
                {  
                  "bestOfferEnabled":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "buyItNowAvailable":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "startTime":[  
                    "2016-04-18T18:45:54.000Z"
                  ],
                  "endTime":[  
                    "2016-04-25T18:45:54.000Z"
                  ],
                  "listingType":[  
                    "Auction"
                  ],
                  "gift":[  
                    "false"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "returnsAccepted":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "condition":[  
                {  
                  "conditionId":[  
                    "3000"
                  ],
                  "conditionDisplayName":[  
                    "Used"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "isMultiVariationListing":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "topRatedListing":[  
                "false"
              ]
            },
            {  
              "itemId":[  
                "172200026135"
              ],
              "title":[  
                "Nikon D5000 12.3 MP Digital SLR Camera (Body Only with Accessories)"
              ],
              "globalId":[  
                "EBAY-US"
              ],
              "primaryCategory":[  
                {  
                  "categoryId":[  
                    "31388"
                  ],
                  "categoryName":[  
                    "Digital Cameras"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "galleryURL":[  
                "http:\/\/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mlRCNAriHPzowbSV9Q7ZFAg\/140.jpg"
              ],
              "viewItemURL":[  
                "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/Nikon-D5000-12-3-MP-Digital-SLR-Camera-Body-Only-Accessories-\/172200026135"
              ],
              "paymentMethod":[  
                "PayPal"
              ],
              "autoPay":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "postalCode":[  
                "02806"
              ],
              "location":[  
                "Barrington,RI,USA"
              ],
              "country":[  
                "US"
              ],
              "shippingInfo":[  
                {  
                  "shippingServiceCost":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"0.0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shippingType":[  
                    "Free"
                  ],
                  "shipToLocations":[  
                    "US"
                  ],
                  "expeditedShipping":[  
                    "true"
                  ],
                  "oneDayShippingAvailable":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "handlingTime":[  
                    "2"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "sellingStatus":[  
                {  
                  "currentPrice":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"119.49"
                    }
                  ],
                  "convertedCurrentPrice":[  
                    {  
                      "@currencyId":"USD",
                      "__value__":"119.49"
                    }
                  ],
                  "bidCount":[  
                    "2"
                  ],
                  "sellingState":[  
                    "EndedWithSales"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "listingInfo":[  
                {  
                  "bestOfferEnabled":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "buyItNowAvailable":[  
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "startTime":[  
                    "2016-05-10T07:22:34.000Z"
                  ],
                  "endTime":[  
                    "2016-05-16T19:22:25.000Z"
                  ],
                  "listingType":[  
                    "Auction"
                  ],
                  "gift":[  
                    "false"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "returnsAccepted":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "condition":[  
                {  
                  "conditionId":[  
                    "3000"
                  ],
                  "conditionDisplayName":[  
                    "Used"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "isMultiVariationListing":[  
                "false"
              ],
              "topRatedListing":[  
                "false"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "paginationOutput":[  
        {  
          "pageNumber":[  
            "1"
          ],
          "entriesPerPage":[  
            "100"
          ],
          "totalPages":[  
            "1"
          ],
          "totalEntries":[  
            "2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I only want to extract the price of the listed item on ebay. Which is I guess the `currentPrice`.

How can I extract only the value of the price to a variable?

Comment: Can you format the json string, please?

Comment: Please, complete this JSON string.

Comment: So many resources out there, many of them here on SO. Have you tried any of them yet?

Comment: What do you mean with complete the string ? if i would post the whole string i would list over 5000 items ...

Comment: Then post a complete JSON string with just 1 or 2 items. We're unable to format your given JSON.

Comment: no i did not tried any resources yet i just searched for an hour hoping to get an answer how to read values from a json format

Comment: I'm seeing some values in your JSON which are questionable. Why are many of the values enclosed in array brackets, such as `["false"]`?

Comment: I am not referring to the string with all the data, I mean as syntactically correct string.
This string is not complete.  the symbols of opening and closing are incorrect ( { [ } ] ).
It's not possible parse the string.

Comment: i edited my question .

Comment: Once you obtain actual json, use a json parser. Do you know what a json parser is?

Comment: no i dont know what that is ...

Comment: You've no chance of progress until you do know. If you still don't know then you need to learn how to use web search.

Comment: This JSON is *horrible*.  Why so many 1-element arrays?  Why strings where booleans and integers are used?  Whoever designed this JSON needs to be re-trained in how JSON works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is horrible JSON.  Whoever designed this data doesn't understand JSON at all.  This JSON is grossly overusing 1-element arrays and string values.  Most of the arrays do not belong at all, and JSON has other data types available (booleans, integers, etc).

In any case, you can use Delphi's built-in [JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/JSON) to parse this JSON, eg:

```
uses
  System.JSON;

var
  json: string;
  obj: TJSONObject;
  completedItems, sresults, items, status, price: TJSONArray;
  I, J, K: Integer;
  currencyId, value: string;
begin
  json := ...; // <-- your JSON string here
  obj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json, 0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    completedItems := obj.Values['findCompletedItemsResponse'] as TJSONArray;
    for I := 0 to completedItems.Count-1 do
    begin
      sresults := (completedItems.Items[I] as TJSONObject).Values['searchResult'] as TJSONArray;
      for J := 0 to sresults.Count-1 do
      begin
        items := (sresults.Items[J] as TJSONObject).Values['item'] as TJSONArray;
        for K := 0 to items.Count-1 do
        begin
          status := (items.Items[K] as TJSONObject).Values['sellingStatus'] as TJSONArray;
          price := ((status.Items[0] as TJSONObject).Values['currentPrice']) as TJSONArray;
          currencyId := price.Values['@currencyId'].Value;
          value := price.Values['__value__'].Value;
          // use price values as needed...
        end;
      end;
    finally
      obj.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Alternatively:

```
uses
  System.JSON, System.JSON.Types;

var
  json: string;
  sreader: TStringReader;
  jreader: TJsonTextReader;
  inCurrentPrice: Boolean;
  currencyId, value: string;
begin
  json := ...; // <-- your JSON string here
  sreader := TStringReader.Create(json);
  try
    jreader := TJsonTextReader.Create(sreader);
    try
      inCurrentPrice := False;
      while jreader.Read do
      begin
        case jreader.TokenType of
          TJsonToken.PropertyName: begin
            if inCurrentPrice then
            begin
              if jreader.Value.AsString = 'currencyId' then begin
                currencyId := jreader.ReadAsString;
              end
              else if jreader.Value.AsString = '__value__' then begin
                value := jreader.ReadAsString;
              end;
            end
            else if jreader.Value.AsString = 'currentPrice' then
            begin
              currencyId := '';
              value := '';
              inCurrentPrice := True;
            end;
          end;
          TJsonToken.EndArray: begin
            if inCurrentPrice then
            begin
              inCurrentPrice := False;
              // use currency values as needed...
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      jreader.Free;
    end;
  finally
    sreader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer ! But dont i have to belong the code above to a data.json ? Or in my case i got the json response in a TMemo . Dont i have to belong the code  to that TMemo ? And how do i do that ? ( i am using the second code snipet you posted)

Comment: @LiamBonactarian: I don't understand what you are asking. But it doesn't really matter where you get the JSON data from as long as you can get it as a `string` for the parser to process (and `TIdHTTP.Get()` can return a `string`, so you don't need to put it in a `TMemo` first).

Comment: Ah ok ! so in the example above you saved the json request in a string ( json:string) ?

Comment: @LiamBonactarian: yes, the JSON is in a `string` variable before being parsed.

Comment: implementing this code to my formula i get two errors : undeclared identifier 'PropertyName' and undeclared identifier EndArray

Comment: Ok thanks its working fine ! but i do not have only one entry. how do i save all prices of the items in an array which counts up to the number of listed items ( total entries ). So at the end i have an array with all prices from the listed items. Would bet nice if you could help me out

Comment: The code I gave you already loops through all available prices. Where the code says "*use price values as needed*" is where you would add each price to your array. You do know how to work with arrays, don't you? That is outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Ah ok ! Yes i know how to work with arrays and i know how to add the values to my array :) ! But i wasn't sure if all values get looped. But know i got it so thanks for your help and your useful answers !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tools like this to generate a envelope for this JSON.

http://www.pgeorgiev.com/?p=1832

The code looks like this:

```
unit Test1;

//  *************************************************
//    Generated By: JsonToDelphiClass - 0.65
//    Project link: https://github.com/PKGeorgiev/Delphi-JsonToDelphiClass
//    Generated On: 2016-06-02 17:46:09
//  *************************************************
//    Created By  : Petar Georgiev - 2014
//    WebSite     : http://pgeorgiev.com
//  *************************************************

interface

uses Generics.Collections, Rest.Json;

type

TConditionClass = class
private
  FConditionDisplayName: TArray<String>;
  FConditionId: TArray<String>;
public
  property conditionDisplayName: TArray<String> read FConditionDisplayName write FConditionDisplayName;
  property conditionId: TArray<String> read FConditionId write FConditionId;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TConditionClass;
end;

TListingInfoClass = class
private
  FBestOfferEnabled: TArray<String>;
  FBuyItNowAvailable: TArray<String>;
  FEndTime: TArray<String>;
  FGift: TArray<String>;
  FListingType: TArray<String>;
  FStartTime: TArray<String>;
public
  property bestOfferEnabled: TArray<String> read FBestOfferEnabled write FBestOfferEnabled;
  property buyItNowAvailable: TArray<String> read FBuyItNowAvailable write FBuyItNowAvailable;
  property endTime: TArray<String> read FEndTime write FEndTime;
  property gift: TArray<String> read FGift write FGift;
  property listingType: TArray<String> read FListingType write FListingType;
  property startTime: TArray<String> read FStartTime write FStartTime;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TListingInfoClass;
end;

TConvertedCurrentPriceClass = class
private
  FAcurrencyId: String;
  F__value__: String;
public
  property AcurrencyId: String read FAcurrencyId write FAcurrencyId;
  property __value__: String read F__value__ write F__value__;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TConvertedCurrentPriceClass;
end;

TCurrentPriceClass = class
private
  FAcurrencyId: String;
  F__value__: String;
public
  property AcurrencyId: String read FAcurrencyId write FAcurrencyId;
  property __value__: String read F__value__ write F__value__;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TCurrentPriceClass;
end;

TSellingStatusClass = class
private
  FBidCount: TArray<String>;
  FConvertedCurrentPrice: TArray<TConvertedCurrentPriceClass>;
  FCurrentPrice: TArray<TCurrentPriceClass>;
  FSellingState: TArray<String>;
public
  property bidCount: TArray<String> read FBidCount write FBidCount;
  property convertedCurrentPrice: TArray<TConvertedCurrentPriceClass> read FConvertedCurrentPrice write FConvertedCurrentPrice;
  property currentPrice: TArray<TCurrentPriceClass> read FCurrentPrice write FCurrentPrice;
  property sellingState: TArray<String> read FSellingState write FSellingState;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TSellingStatusClass;
end;

TShippingInfoClass = class
private
  FExpeditedShipping: TArray<String>;
  FHandlingTime: TArray<String>;
  FOneDayShippingAvailable: TArray<String>;
  FShipToLocations: TArray<String>;
  FShippingType: TArray<String>;
public
  property expeditedShipping: TArray<String> read FExpeditedShipping write FExpeditedShipping;
  property handlingTime: TArray<String> read FHandlingTime write FHandlingTime;
  property oneDayShippingAvailable: TArray<String> read FOneDayShippingAvailable write FOneDayShippingAvailable;
  property shipToLocations: TArray<String> read FShipToLocations write FShipToLocations;
  property shippingType: TArray<String> read FShippingType write FShippingType;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TShippingInfoClass;
end;

TProductIdClass = class
private
  FAtype: String;
  F__value__: String;
public
  property Atype: String read FAtype write FAtype;
  property __value__: String read F__value__ write F__value__;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TProductIdClass;
end;

TPrimaryCategoryClass = class
private
  FCategoryId: TArray<String>;
  FCategoryName: TArray<String>;
public
  property categoryId: TArray<String> read FCategoryId write FCategoryId;
  property categoryName: TArray<String> read FCategoryName write FCategoryName;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TPrimaryCategoryClass;
end;

TItemClass = class
private
  FAutoPay: TArray<String>;
  FCondition: TArray<TConditionClass>;
  FCountry: TArray<String>;
  FGalleryURL: TArray<String>;
  FGlobalId: TArray<String>;
  FIsMultiVariationListing: TArray<String>;
  FItemId: TArray<String>;
  FListingInfo: TArray<TListingInfoClass>;
  FLocation: TArray<String>;
  FPaymentMethod: TArray<String>;
  FPostalCode: TArray<String>;
  FPrimaryCategory: TArray<TPrimaryCategoryClass>;
  FProductId: TArray<TProductIdClass>;
  FReturnsAccepted: TArray<String>;
  FSellingStatus: TArray<TSellingStatusClass>;
  FShippingInfo: TArray<TShippingInfoClass>;
  FTitle: TArray<String>;
  FTopRatedListing: TArray<String>;
  FViewItemURL: TArray<String>;
public
  property autoPay: TArray<String> read FAutoPay write FAutoPay;
  property condition: TArray<TConditionClass> read FCondition write FCondition;
  property country: TArray<String> read FCountry write FCountry;
  property galleryURL: TArray<String> read FGalleryURL write FGalleryURL;
  property globalId: TArray<String> read FGlobalId write FGlobalId;
  property isMultiVariationListing: TArray<String> read FIsMultiVariationListing write FIsMultiVariationListing;
  property itemId: TArray<String> read FItemId write FItemId;
  property listingInfo: TArray<TListingInfoClass> read FListingInfo write FListingInfo;
  property location: TArray<String> read FLocation write FLocation;
  property paymentMethod: TArray<String> read FPaymentMethod write FPaymentMethod;
  property postalCode: TArray<String> read FPostalCode write FPostalCode;
  property primaryCategory: TArray<TPrimaryCategoryClass> read FPrimaryCategory write FPrimaryCategory;
  property productId: TArray<TProductIdClass> read FProductId write FProductId;
  property returnsAccepted: TArray<String> read FReturnsAccepted write FReturnsAccepted;
  property sellingStatus: TArray<TSellingStatusClass> read FSellingStatus write FSellingStatus;
  property shippingInfo: TArray<TShippingInfoClass> read FShippingInfo write FShippingInfo;
  property title: TArray<String> read FTitle write FTitle;
  property topRatedListing: TArray<String> read FTopRatedListing write FTopRatedListing;
  property viewItemURL: TArray<String> read FViewItemURL write FViewItemURL;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TItemClass;
end;

TSearchResultClass = class
private
  FAcount: String;
  FItem: TArray<TItemClass>;
public
  property Acount: String read FAcount write FAcount;
  property item: TArray<TItemClass> read FItem write FItem;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TSearchResultClass;
end;

TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass = class
private
  FAck: TArray<String>;
  FSearchResult: TArray<TSearchResultClass>;
  FTimestamp: TArray<String>;
  FVersion: TArray<String>;
public
  property ack: TArray<String> read FAck write FAck;
  property searchResult: TArray<TSearchResultClass> read FSearchResult write FSearchResult;
  property timestamp: TArray<String> read FTimestamp write FTimestamp;
  property version: TArray<String> read FVersion write FVersion;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass;
end;

TRootClass = class
private
  FFindCompletedItemsResponse: TArray<TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass>;
public
  property findCompletedItemsResponse: TArray<TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass> read FFindCompletedItemsResponse write FFindCompletedItemsResponse;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TRootClass;
end;

implementation

{TConditionClass}


function TConditionClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TConditionClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TConditionClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TConditionClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TListingInfoClass}


function TListingInfoClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TListingInfoClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TListingInfoClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TListingInfoClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TConvertedCurrentPriceClass}


function TConvertedCurrentPriceClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TConvertedCurrentPriceClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TConvertedCurrentPriceClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TConvertedCurrentPriceClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TCurrentPriceClass}


function TCurrentPriceClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TCurrentPriceClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TCurrentPriceClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TCurrentPriceClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TSellingStatusClass}

destructor TSellingStatusClass.Destroy;
var
  LcurrentPriceItem: TCurrentPriceClass;
  LconvertedCurrentPriceItem: TConvertedCurrentPriceClass;
begin

 for LcurrentPriceItem in FCurrentPrice do
   LcurrentPriceItem.free;
 for LconvertedCurrentPriceItem in FConvertedCurrentPrice do
   LconvertedCurrentPriceItem.free;

  inherited;
end;

function TSellingStatusClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TSellingStatusClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TSellingStatusClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TSellingStatusClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TShippingInfoClass}


function TShippingInfoClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TShippingInfoClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TShippingInfoClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TShippingInfoClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TProductIdClass}


function TProductIdClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TProductIdClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TProductIdClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TProductIdClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TPrimaryCategoryClass}


function TPrimaryCategoryClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TPrimaryCategoryClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TPrimaryCategoryClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TPrimaryCategoryClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TItemClass}

destructor TItemClass.Destroy;
var
  LprimaryCategoryItem: TPrimaryCategoryClass;
  LproductIdItem: TProductIdClass;
  LshippingInfoItem: TShippingInfoClass;
  LsellingStatusItem: TSellingStatusClass;
  LlistingInfoItem: TListingInfoClass;
  LconditionItem: TConditionClass;
begin

 for LprimaryCategoryItem in FPrimaryCategory do
   LprimaryCategoryItem.free;
 for LproductIdItem in FProductId do
   LproductIdItem.free;
 for LshippingInfoItem in FShippingInfo do
   LshippingInfoItem.free;
 for LsellingStatusItem in FSellingStatus do
   LsellingStatusItem.free;
 for LlistingInfoItem in FListingInfo do
   LlistingInfoItem.free;
 for LconditionItem in FCondition do
   LconditionItem.free;

  inherited;
end;

function TItemClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TItemClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TItemClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TItemClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TSearchResultClass}

destructor TSearchResultClass.Destroy;
var
  LitemItem: TItemClass;
begin

 for LitemItem in FItem do
   LitemItem.free;

  inherited;
end;

function TSearchResultClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TSearchResultClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TSearchResultClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TSearchResultClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass}

destructor TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass.Destroy;
var
  LsearchResultItem: TSearchResultClass;
begin

 for LsearchResultItem in FSearchResult do
   LsearchResultItem.free;

  inherited;
end;

function TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass>(AJsonString)
end;

{TRootClass}

destructor TRootClass.Destroy;
var
  LfindCompletedItemsResponseItem: TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass;
begin

 for LfindCompletedItemsResponseItem in FFindCompletedItemsResponse do
   LfindCompletedItemsResponseItem.free;

  inherited;
end;

function TRootClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TRootClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TRootClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TRootClass>(AJsonString)
end;

end.
```

Once you have it, a code similar to this you can get the value you need.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  cr:TRootClass;
  rc:TFindCompletedItemsResponseClass;
  sr:TSearchResultClass;
  it:TItemClass;
  ss:TSellingStatusClass;
  cp:TCurrentPriceClass;
  str:string;
begin
  cr := TRootClass.FromJsonString(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  rc := cr.findCompletedItemsResponse[0];
  sr := rc.searchResult[0];
  it := sr.item[0];
  ss := it.sellingStatus[0];
  cp := ss.currentPrice[0];
  // current price
  Str := cp.__value__;      <<=======
end;
```

Regards.

PD: Please take longer to perform better questions to get better answers.